# MATLAB Incorrect number of right hand side elements

Tags: matlab, data-structures, matrix, multidimensional-array

Matlab's syntax is infuriating, specifically with structs. In the Bioinformatics toolkit, there is a method called jcampread(File) which is described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/jcampread.html).

In the description, the method jcampread() takes a Filepath and outputs into a struct called jcampStruct. From my understanding, in Matlab, you don't declare return variable types like you do in C: you just give the return variable a name and it somehow knows that the return of jcampread() method will be a jcampStruct. How it does, I have no idea, but it does.

I put in the code exactly how their example shows in step 4 of the Example section, and I get the following error message back from Matlab:

```
    Incorrect number of right hand side elements in
    dot name assignment.  Missing [] around left hand
    side is a likely cause.
    Error in jcampread>ntupleRead (line 510)
        dataBlock.ZName = name{Zidx};
    Error in jcampread (line 192)
        dataBlocks = ntupleRead(fid);
```

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/11443) site says the problem occurs "when f has more than one matrix element." Code is below:

```
    »f.a = [1 0]
    f = 
        a: [1 0]
    »f.b = [1 2]
    f = 
        a: [1 0]
        b: [1 2]
    »f = setfield(f,'a',[2 2])
    f = 
        a: [2 2]
        b: [1 2]
    »f(2).a=1
    f = 
    1x2 struct array with fields:
        a
        b
    »f = setfield(f,'a',[2 2])
    ??? Error using ==> setfield
    Incorrect number of right hand side elements in dot name assignment. 
    Missing [] around left hand side is a likely cause.
```

I assume this means the matrix f looks like this:

```
    f = [ [a1; b1]; [a2; b2]; ]
    f = [ [[2 2]; [1 2]]; [[1]; []]; ]
```

When they tried to update f.a which was set to

```
    f.a = [[2 2]; [1]]
```

...to a single element [2 2], it doesn't like that because f.a is currently a matrix with 2 vector elements. Basically if you are going to reassign f.a (all elements of the attribute a of matrix f), you have to reassign f.a to have the same number of elements as it currently has.

I *think* that is why this error is occuring in the setfield example.

My question: how does this apply to jcampread()? jcampStruct is literally a structure with the same attributes, and those attributes are assigned only once. I do not understand:

a. How matlab knows the return value of jcampread() is a jcampStruct, and
b. Why (given that it knows (a)), the 'Incorrect number of right hand..' error message is firing here.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: just a site note: There are no nested arrays in Matlab. `[ [a1; b1]; [a2; b2]; ]` is another way to write `[ a1; b1; a2; b2; ]`

Comment: You also cannot create uneven matrices.  As such, what you have for `f.a` when you are trying to update the matrix will not work so what you have mentioned is indeed correct.  Also, try doing a direct assignment of `f.a = ...` rather than using `setfield`.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a **non scalar structure** and there is no way to assign at once, i.e. without a loop, a different value to the same field of each sub-structure.What does it mean?

### Scalar structure

```
s.a = 1;

size(s)
ans =
     1     1
```

Now, adding fields doesn't change the size of the structure:

```
s.b = 2;
size(s)
ans =
     1     1
```

### Non-scalar structure

However, assigning a value to the **same** field, but into a position > 1 of the structure, will grow it a **non-scalar** one:

```
s(2).a = 3
size(s)
ans =
     1     2
```

Also, notice how the sub-structure in position 2 replicates/pre-allocates the fields of the initial structure even though you assigned to `a` alone:

```
s(2)
ans = 
     a: 3
     b: []
```

### Pointers

Additionally, the field  `s(2).b` is just an empty pointer:

```
whos s
Name    Size  Bytes  Class   
s       1x2   496    struct
```

and by adding a scalar double (8 bytes), we get

```
s(2).b = 4;

whos s
Name    Size  Bytes  Class   
s       1x2   608    struct
```

### Pro of non-scalar structure

What you can do with a non-scalar structure, is retrieve one field across all sub-structure (considering you don't run into concatenation issues):

```
for ii = 1:100
    s(ii).a = rand(1,2);
end

cat(1,s.a)
```

the last command will concatenate all values of a single field from all sub-structure into a 100 by 2 array.

### Cons

To assign different values across the sub-structures, even if the same field, you need to loop (as above in the `for loop`).

At most you could `deal()` the same values into one field across all sub-structures:

```
clear s
[s(1:100)] = deal([1, 2]);
```

Comment: All of this is really great, but I still don't feel I understand why this error is being thrown for jcampread(); Have you gotten the chance to take a look at the method? There is a sample .DX file in the link I posted above. Thanks for your in depth response on Matlab operators!

Comment: @areyoujokingme You need to post the snippet of code that is generating the error. Actually, it might be that the file is not found, or is irregular.

Comment: Hey, Oleg. In my first paragraph I gave a link to this address: http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/jcampread.html. The exact code I used is the code in #4 (scroll down). I would attach the DX file I'm using, but I cannot, due to legal issues. However, my DX file contains the same general format, but is more complex than their very simple DX file example.

Comment: I am beginning to fear this is a version thing. I think jcampread() only works for ISAS version 5 DX files, not for Bruker version 6 DX files, which is what I'm currently running. Gah. I thought it was something about Matlab.

Comment: @areyoujokingme You can try to put a break point and check in debug mode what's going on. Also, you can submit a request to TMW for making it compatible with the newer version (However note that the docs say they support "Versions 4.24, 5, or 6 of the JCAMP-DX format"). I can't help more than that since I don't have that toolbox.